# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') discord.js V13 command interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I get this error when  the command executed the command is an unmute command
and my handler  is a slash command

> when i set the the member as member type in options its work fine but
> i want it with ID
> if anyone have a solutions and thx

```
        if(target.roles.cache.has(muterole)) {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```

this the command :

```
const { MessageEmbed, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");


module.exports = {
    name: "unmute",
    description: "Unmute a Member",
    permission: "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
    options: [
        {
            name: "member",
            description: "Member ID",
            required: true,
            type: "STRING"
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "provide unmute reason",
            required: true,
            type: "STRING"
        }
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { guild, channel, member, options } = interaction;

        const target = options.getString("member");
        const reason = options.getString("reason");
        const logchannel = guild.channels.cache.get("877754209016086588");
        const muterole = guild.roles.cache.get("944200095040167946");
        console.log(target);
        const logembed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("AQUA")
        .setAuthor({ name: `${member.user.tag}`, iconURL: `${member.user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 })}` })
        .setDescription(`
${target} got unmuted 
        by : ${member}
        reason : ${reason}
        `)
        .setTimestamp();
        const response = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`
${target} unmuted
        `);
        if(target.roles.cache.has(muterole)) {
            await target.roles.remove(muterole);
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [response], ephemeral: true});
            await logchannel.send({
                    content: `${member}`,
                    embeds: [logembed]
            });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({content: `${target} is not muted`, ephemeral: true});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console log your guild object. I bet there is not a guild.channels node.

Comment: In your current code, the `target` variable only contains the id of the member who you want to unmute. You cannot check if the id has roles or not. Instead, you can use: `const target = guild.members.cache.get(options.getString("member"))` and then do whatever you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `USER` type supports **Snowflake Ids**, **User Mentions** & **Member Mentions**.
- You can add `type: "USER"` and use

```js
const member = interaction.options.getMember("target"); // for a GuildMember
const user = interaction.options.getUser("target"); // for a User
```

- Once again, it supports user IDs and mentions.
- Using a string for fetching a member/user isn't efficient because if the ID provided is invalid, the bot returns `null` and might lead to a crash.